# getting "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00DABE0" in MediaCapture sample of c#/xaml metro style app

Tags: c#, exception, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, audio-recording

I have checked this  [MediaCapture](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622) sample. I tried to record audio but when I press "StartDevice" button, I got "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00DABE0". My audio device is working perfectly, I have checked with Windows 8's built in sound recording app. Can anyone please help me to sort out this issue ?

**I have tried the same app with HTML5/JS sample, it records the audio but C#/XAML app gives exception.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution

change this line into sample

```
await m_mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();
```

to this

```
await m_mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync(settings);
```